# Laravel secure routes handling with config

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I have seen in documentation that for secure routes **Laravel** provides function `secure_url` over just `url` and it provide redirect method

```
redirect()->secure('/path');
```

Now this seem very confusing as to switch protocol we need change code. And worst part is we may need to change pre-built **Auth** controllers in laravel.

My question is if there is any better way to switch to **https** from configurations. And if not possible than why? If required we can fork laravel and add this feature.

Comment: I didn't use it much, but as far as I know, if you already use `https` protocol (and PHP knows it is being used, either via `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` or `X-Forwarded-Proto` or something like that), laravel will use https every time you use your redirection/url. I may be wrong on that matter, though

Answer (score 2):

The solution I used for this was to create a secure middleware. It checks to see if the request is secure. If not redirect it to a secure one.

Firstly create a middleware in your middleware directory

```
    <?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class SecureMiddleware {

        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
             if (!$request->secure()) {
                    return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
                }
            return $next($request);
        }

    }
```

Register it in your Kernel.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'          => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic'    => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest'         => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'securage'      => 'App\Http\Middleware\SecureMiddleware',
    ];
```

Then use a route group to specify where you want the secure routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'securage'], function() {
/* Routes here */
});
```

Comment: I am also using similar middleware, but isn't it an overhead. My question is why laravel provides two different function for links which are url and secure_url.

Comment: @anwerjunaid the functions are calling the same base function for example secure_url is just calling url() with last argument($secure) as true, so you can call url() with $secure as true